# Understanding proof of $(m+n+2)^2 \neq 3(mn + 1)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-explanation

The problem is: Prove that there are no integers $m$ and $n$ such that:
$$(m+n+2)^2 = 3(mn + 1)$$
I found the explanation for the problem solution, **but I still don't understand it.**

Here's the solution I found:

> If there are numbers $m$ and $n$ such that: $(m+n+2)^2 = 3(mn + 1)$, then $3 
> |(m+n+2)^2 \implies 9|(m+n+2)^2$ and $3 | (mn+1)$, that means that numbers $m$ and $n$ cannot be divisible by $3$ and they cannot have the same remainder after dividing by $3$. Let's rewrite $m$ and $n$ as $m = 3p + 1$ and $n = 3q + 2$, but then we have $m+n+2 = 3(p+q+1) + 2$ which is impossible since $3 | m+n+2$

The only thing I don't understand is why $3 | (mn+1)$?
Can someone explain this to me? Thanks.

Comment: Why $3\mid (mn+1)$? Because $9$ divides the LHS, so $9$ divides the RHS, namely $3(mn+1)$. This implies it.

Comment: Now I understand. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

For any prime $p$, if $p \mid n^2$, then $p^2 \mid n^2$, a result of [Euclid's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_lemma) (for any prime $p$, if $p \mid ab$, then either $p \mid a$ or $p \mid b$).

Comment: @DietrichBurde Thanks, you're obviously right, not sure what was going through my mind when I wrote that.

Comment: No problem, now it is fine.

Answer (score 0):

#### Alternative proof

$$(m+n+2)^2-3mn-3=0$$

$$\iff  m^2 - m (n -4) + n^2 + 4 n + 1=0 $$

$$\begin{align}\Delta &=-3 n^2 - 24 n + 12\\
&=60 - 3 (n + 4)^2\end{align}$$

$$60 - 3 (n + 4)^2≥0, ~ 60 - 3 (n + 4)^2=T^2, T\in\mathbb Z$$

This means, such $n\in\mathbb Z$ doesn't exist.

---

**Small supplement:**

$$\begin{align}0&≤60 - 3 (n + 4)^2\\
&=60 - 3 (|n + 4|)^2\\
&=T^2,~T\in\mathbb Z \end{align}$$

All possible cases are as follows:

$$|n+4|:=1,2,3,4.$$

Comment: Awesome! Thank you!

Comment: @Filip Your question was answered in the comment.  That's why I didn't add it to the answer.

Comment: No worries. Thanks for showing me another way of proving this.

Comment: @Filip You're welcome.